# is optimal solution of the original problem always the same as the relaxed problem Or is this just an accident?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, mixed-integer-programming, relaxations

I want to solve the following problem with GAMS software:

$ \min y+\frac{1}{0.05} \sum_s p^s u^s $

$s.t$

$\sum_{j \in V}\delta_j=b$

$\sum_{j\in W^s} x_j^s +q^s=1  \  \  \forall s\in S$

$ x_j^s \le \delta_j  \  \  \forall s\in S , j\in W^s$

$u^s \ge \sum_{j\in W^s}  d_j^s x_j^s +M^sq^s-y \ \ \forall s\in S$

$\delta_j \in \{0,1\} \  \ \forall j$

$q^s \in \{0,1\} \  \ \forall s\in S$

$x_j^s \in \{0,1\} \  \ \forall j ,s\in S$

$y \ge 0 ,u^s \ge 0 \  \  \forall s\in S$

that $\delta_j , q^s , x_j^s , y,u^s $ are variables. $p^s , M^s , d_j^s, b $ are parameter,(The parameters ($M^s , d_j^s, b$) are all positive and integer and $p^s=\frac{1}{|S|}$).$M^s$  is properly big penalty.$V$ is e set of nodes with index $j $ .
and $W^s$ are subset of $V$. Also $s$ is index of set $S$ scenario.

When the problem is solved with binary variables ($\delta_j ,  x _j^s$), the answer obtained is the same as the answer of the problem when the variable $x_j^s$ is relaxed.

I made this comparison with various parameters  $d_j^s, b$  and different size $S$, and each time the answers are identical.

Can it be proved that the answer to the original  problem (when $\delta_j ,  x _j^s$ are binary) is always the same as the relaxed problem (when $ x _j^s$ are non negative)?

Or is this just an accident?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you relax the integrality of $q^s$, too, or just $\delta_j$ and $x_j^s$?

Comment: Hi @LarrySnyder610 , I only  relaxed $x_j^s$ . thanks

Comment: I forgot to wrote this constraints $x_j^s \le \delta_j \ \ \forall j ,s$ , I edited my question.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Thanks so much! Do you mean in your last sentences that x always takes a value of 0 or 1? but ,When $x_j^s \ge 0$ , it also take  decimal values, and the the Optimal solution is the same as the Optimal solution when $x_j^s \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: I mean that if you *allow* $x_j^s \ge 0$, it will still be $\in \{0,1\}$ in the optimal solution. That is what your original question was asking, right?

Comment: I wanted to know is it possible to prove that when the $x_j^s$ is continuous or when the $x_j^s$ binary the optimal value is the same? Or getting the same value in optimal solution is just an accident?

Comment: My answer below argues that whether $x_j^s$ are continuous or binary, the optimal *solution* will be the same. This also implies that the optimal *objective function values* will be the same.

Comment: you'r awesome!  I can't thank you enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if you relax $x_j^s \in \{0,1\}$ to $x_j^s \ge 0$, there will always be an optimal solution in which $x_j^s \in \{0,1\}$. Here's why.

First, if $q^s=1$, then clearly $x_j^s=0$ for all $j$. Suppose $q^s=0$. Then the fourth constraint becomes
$$u^s \ge \sum_{j\in W^s} d_j^sx_j^s - y \quad \forall s\in S.$$
Suppose that $0< x_1^s,x_2^s < 1$, and that $x_1^s+x_2^s=1$. (If there are more than 2 fractional $x_j^s$ values, the logic is similar.) Assume WLOG that $d_1^s \le d_2^s$. By the third constraint, we know that $\delta_1 = \delta_2 = 1$.

So, suppose we set $x_1^2=1$ and $x_2^s=0$. The first constraint is not affected. The second and third constraints are still satisfied. The fourth constraint is still satisfied too, but it's also possible that we can make $u^s$ smaller, in which case the objective function improves.

Therefore, there is always an optimal solution in which the $x_j^s$ are binary.